# Check before Mark Complete

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I have custom activity entity. I want to check weather Product Sample Sent On field is populated, before Completing it.

I used this code, and added it to form, as on save event, but it doesn't work.

```
function checkMandatory(executionObj)
{
   debugger;
  if (executionObj.getEventArgs().getSaveMode() == 58) {
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ad_sampleproductssenton").getValue() == null) {
      alert("Date is mandatory when completing activity");
      executionObj.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
      Mscrm.CommandBarActions.$O = false;
      return false;
    }
  }

} //(this is line 65)
```

Does anyone has the idea what is the potential problem?
Here is the  the error reported:

Microsoft Dynamics CRM Error Report Contents:

```
<CrmScriptErrorReport>
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input</Message>
   <Line>65</Line>
   <URL>/%7B636106488660001088%7D/WebResources/ad_productSampleRequest?ver=-479036267</URL>
   <PageURL>/form/page.aspx?lcid=1033&themeId=f499443d-2082-4938-8842-e7ee62de9a23&tstamp=581317&updateTimeStamp=636099264463033785&userts=131195256708212045&ver=-479036267#etc=10010&extraqs=%3fetc%3d10010&pagemode=iframe&pagetype=entityrecord&counter=1475052420068</PageURL>
   <Function>anonymousror:Unexpectedendofinput</Function>
   <FunctionRaw>SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input</FunctionRaw>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>anonymousror:Unexpectedendofinput</Function>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
  <ClientInformation>
   <BrowserUserAgent>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36</BrowserUserAgent>
   <BrowserLanguage>undefined</BrowserLanguage>
   <SystemLanguage>undefined</SystemLanguage>
   <UserLanguage>undefined</UserLanguage>
   <ScreenResolution>1366x768</ScreenResolution>
   <ClientName>Web</ClientName>
   <ClienState>Online</ClienState>
   <ClientTime>2016-09-28T10:47:00</ClientTime>
  </ClientInformation>
  <ServerInformation>
    <OrgLanguage>1033</OrgLanguage>
    <OrgCulture>1033</OrgCulture>
    <UserLanguage>1033</UserLanguage>
    <UserCulture>1033</UserCulture>
    <OrgID>{3567FFBD-0F48-E611-80BD-00155DFCDF39}</OrgID>
    <UserID>{033FC4B4-2148-E611-80BD-00155DFCDF39}</UserID>
    <CRMVersion>8.0.0.1088</CRMVersion>
  </ServerInformation>
</CrmScriptErrorReport>
```

[image]

I deletet the problematic line. But it still doesn't work.
Here is how i registered this function. Is this ok?

Andrii here is the explanation:

I found that there is some background code for mark complete:

```
if (!Mscrm.CommandBarActions.$O) {
        Mscrm.CommandBarActions.$O = true;
        var $v_5 = new Xrm.SaveOptions;
        $v_5.useSchedulingEngine = false;
        Xrm.Page.data.save($v_5).then($v_0, $v_1); //here is the call to your save-method
    }
```

In this code their variable Mscrm.CommandBarActions.$O is immediatelly set to true after check if it is false.
Only if this variable is false you can call the save-method again. Internally they set this variable only to true, if you don't Abort the save-process 
It is supposed to set this variable to false again.

But, for me now,  first world problem is to make this work, even once.
I can try to delete this line of code if it looks like a obstacle, I just want to know if there is maybe some other reason. For example, this function has an argument, is it something about the argument that might be a problem here? Or something else...

Comment: Milos, What does following line of code "Mscrm.CommandBarActions.$O = false;" mean?

Comment: This is something i found in some example on internet. I will giveyou explanation in a moment.

Comment: I would suggest to remove that line because this code is obviously not supported.

Comment: I added the explanation in a comment, and will tr to delete this line of code.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Were you able to identify where the error is occurring?

Comment: When i click 'mark complete' it just saves the record, id doesn't even start wit my function. There is just error report.

Comment: Lett me know if you need some additional info

Comment: What does your webresource contain except your onsave handler? Can you please post full code of your webresource?

Comment: Hey Andrii, your suggestion gave me the idea to putt the rest of the code in a comment and, here is a progress now, it partially works.

Comment: Now it checks if there is a date and it is not possible to save this document if tehre is not date. There is one more thing i need to solve now, i need it to save the document anyhow, but not to mark as completed if there is no date. I don't know how to separate these two actions

Comment: Should work after removing this line --> `Mscrm.CommandBarActions.$O = false;`

Comment: @MilosNikolic `Re: still be able to save the record without allowing mark as complete`, try calling Xrm.Page.data.save(); explicitly, this save will not have the same save mode as mark as complete.

Comment: Did it and it works now. Thanks!